# PHP How to check if MySQL result contains value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following code:

```
$getfreq = mysql_query("SELECT wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE wp_term_relationships.object_id = '1737'");
```

The above results in phpymyadmin in returning 5 values: 345 456 569 634 723

Now, using PHP I want to check the contents of $getfreq to see if it contains 569.

I've tried doing this:

```
if (in_array(569,$getfreq,TRUE) {
    echo "Success!";
} else if (in_array(654,$getfreq,TRUE) {
    echo "Not good";
} else {
    echo "Failure";
}
```

But this doesn't work.

Doing this:

```
print_r($getfreq);
```

Results in: Array().

Any ideas?

Comment: you shouldn't be using mysql_* use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: How come? This is news to me...

Comment: mysql_* has been replaced by mysqli (mysql improved), PDO is also an alternative.  If you look at the top of any mysql_* function you will see it is advised you always use one of the newer improved extensions.  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Answer (score 1):

`$getfreq` is not an array its a result resource. In order to get the actual row in an array you need to call one of the fetch functions on the result for example:

`$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getfreq)`

Then do `in_array` on the `$row`.

> this doesn't work. If i use print_r($row), I only get Array ( [term_taxonomy_id] => 345 ). In phpmyadmin, my query returns the above mentioned 5 results. What is happening to the rest?

Thats because you need to loop through the entire result set. That is the result for a single row:

```
while ( false !== ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getfreq))) {
   // make your comparison for each row   
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work. If i use print_r($row), I only get Array ( [term_taxonomy_id] => 345 ). In phpmyadmin, my query returns the above mentioned 5 results. What is happening to the rest?

Comment: Thats because you need to loop through the entire result set. That is the result for a single row.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
$res = mysql_fetch_array($getfreq);
```

then

```
if (in_array(569,$res,TRUE) {....
```

Comment: this doesn't work. If i use print_r($res), I only get Array ( [0] => 345 [term_taxonomy_id] => 345 ). In phpmyadmin, my query returns the above mentioned 5 results. What is happening to the rest?

Comment: I get array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "345" ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> string(3) "345" }. Still don't know what is happening to the rest...

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getfreq)) {
    if ($row[term_taxonomy_id] == 345) {
        echo "WORKS!";
    }
}
```